# Using AngularJs (WebService) instead of Django View-Template

Tags: django, web-services, angularjs, django-templates, django-views

We have developed a django app and finished all view and templates. There are many controls in template and views. Our new frontend partner says us :

> I want to use angularjs, so develop a webservice for me.

So, what is advantages and disadvantages ? Why we might omit the written view and templates?

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> AngularJS is modern javascript framework for creating complex web
>   applications within the browser. It focuses on strong separation of
>   concerns (MVC) and dependency injection to encourage creating
>   maintainable (and testable) modules that can be integrated to develop
>   rich client side functionality.
>
> With the advent of more interactive web applications, a ReSTful API
>   can be leveraged by rich client interfaces to expose and interact with
>   your application's data model. AngularJS is a great companion because
>   of its clean separation of controls. AngularJS's modular architecture
>   involves a little bit of setup. **Your app is composed of modules
>   which define services, directives and controllers that
>   compartmentalize the functionality for cleaner separation.**
>
> Part of the power of AngularJS, is that it provides [reactive
>   programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) leveraging their javascript-like expression language.
>   **We can simply define a template that references variables, and our page will automatically refresh when changes are made to those
>   variables.**

Django Rest Framework is best choice to expose your web services/apis as it uses less code.

i might think you have to omit/keep aside the existing views/urls as it uses django forms to store the data etc. Whereas you have to handle the json data (applicable if you not use django rest framework)

reference [link](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html)

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesh Bachu, I'm using Django Rest Framework for mobile devices. But I want to know why I have to omit the existing view and templates? All things is ready and only css may changes. Why I have to  move everything as webservice?

Comment: @TheNone if you want to implement the UI with AngularJs then it requires the models(json) as AngularJs is MVC based arch. so in order to support AngularJs, you need to write other views or modify existing views to give JSON response instead of templates and forms. you can keep the earlier views also instead of omiting it.